# Different regex conditions on same string

Tags: regex

I am trying to implement a regex for phone numbers, based on our business logic.

What the customer wants is that the phone must contain between 8 and 15 characters of numbers, and also can contain any spaces and dots anywhere which doesn't add to the count of numbers. So, theoretically this should be valid:

```
3          ....            44444444
```

Because it contains 9 numbers.

I can't really go further on

```
~[0-9\.\ ]{8,15}$
```

but obviously it counts dots and spaces to the limit too.

Is it even possible to implement it via regex?

Comment: This is a very common FAQ.  The usual recommendation is to ditch the insignificant punctuation, then do a simple length check on the remaining number string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Regex attempt:

```
^(?:[ .]*\d){8,15}[ .]*$
```

This will match 8 to 15 digits, with any number of space or dot happening anywhere in between.

- The non-captured group, `(?:[ .]*\d)`, matches any digit preceded by any number of dot or space, `{8,15}` ensures the range on numbers
- `[ .]*$` matches any number of dot or space at the end

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vL2lP7/5)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, regular expressions cannot validate this. However you could maybe globally remove all whitespace and dots and then try to match a regex that is `^[[:digit:]]{8,15}$`